Storybook for simple ionic components
I'm keen to use storybook to test my custom building blocks in isolation. I make use of a lot of customised ionic components. From my reading of storybook, I can see how it is easy enough to create custom components and test them. However, I would like to put the bulk of my customisation logic into global css style sheets instead of creating loads of new components.
How would I test this in storybook?
If I create a super simple example to illustrate...
The following story will build fine:
import { centered, in_header } from '~/.storybook/utils';
import { componentWrapperDecorator } from '@storybook/angular';

import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/angular';

import { IonButton } from '@ionic/angular';
type Story = StoryObj<IonButton>;
const meta: Meta<IonButton> = {
  title: 'Ionic/Monkey Buttons',
  component: IonButton,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  decorators: [
    centered({ horizontalMarginPx: 20 }),
    componentWrapperDecorator(() => `
      <ion-button> My Button </ion-button>
  `),
  ]
};
export default meta;

export const PrimaryFull: Story = {

};

export const PrimarySecondary: Story = {
      args: {
        // label: 'My Button',
        color: 'tertiary'
      }
};

But it's not clear to me how I can add custom classes to the story to test my actual usage. For example in my global scss, I would put something like this:
    ion-button {
      // Rounded Corners
      --border-radius: var(--button-radius);

      // Defaults
      display: inline-flex; // Make sure button doesn't take full width by default
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-transform: none !important; // Disable uppercase globally for ion-buttons (need to force it!)
      padding: 0; // Ionic adds 5px padding top & bottom
      margin: 0; // remove outer margin (beyond the border-box)
      box-sizing: border-box !important;

      // Icon
      &.icon-present {
        .button-text {
          margin-left: 8px;
          text-align: left;
          text-transform: none !important;
        }
        ion-icon {
          margin-left: auto;
        }
      }

      &.icon-absent {
        .button-text {
          text-align: center;
          margin: 0 auto;
          text-transform: none !important;
        }
      }
    }

It's a bit of a weird example, but how would I apply the class icon-present to the ion-button element in the story?
I think what I actually want to do here is is use CSS to check if the ion-button has a nested ion-icon child element, and then apply the icon-present OR icon-absent classes conditionally to the ion-button. The challenge then is to create different componetnWrapper cases for each story. Hmmm. Maybe that would answer the class part too???
And a more obvious question, is it possible to change the button text at the story level?
